# IIS 8.0 Not Looking in Subfolder

Tags: angular, iis, webpack, iis-8, angular-cli

I have an application hosted within another website using IIS 8.0 [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoST4.png) (In case it's relevant, it's an Angular 2 project using CLI and Webpack). I'm hosting my app at https://example.org/MyApp. Unfortunately, when I try to run the site, I receive a 404 error for each file I have referenced. The browser is trying to look for my files at https://example.org/file.jpg when they are actually hosted at https://example.org/MyApp/file.jpg. Is there any way to tell IIS to search for these files in the subdirectory instead of the root folder?

As a note, Webpack uses relative file paths for all bundling, so changing these file paths to be absolute is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your index.html to set the `<base href>`

For example `<base href="/MyApp/">`

Comment: Can you explain why this solution fixes the problem? What exactly does it do?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue. Everything located in my assets folder (https://example.org/MyApp/assets/file.jpg) still returns 404 Not Found because the site is looking for them in https://example.org/assets/file.jpg instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm beating a dead horse here, however this seems to work pretty solid:

Basically a mixup of setting base-href and IIS-url-rewrite.

1. build ng-app with `--base-href /myAppDir/`
2. Ensure URL-Rewrite module is available for your IIS-Website
3. add a web.config-file to the website's root folder.
4. edit file from 3. to be like, for example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp/" />
            <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />-->
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

5. You most likely want to use another regular expression as `match-url` to match your website's needs.

Taken from:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, Johan; you're totally right. Edited the post.